# Is it possible to draw a pdf vector image inside a larger pdf page?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, core-graphics

I have a pdf vector file that I want to display as part of a pdf document. I don't really want to change it to an UIImage file. I just feel that doing so will degrade the quality. What Im attempting to do is take the url of the pdf and add it to the main pdf document. I've worked out the size of my pdf vector and created a CGRect as follows:

```
func drawPDFfromURL(url: NSURL) {
    guard let document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url) else { return nil }
    guard let page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1) else { return nil }

    let pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, .MediaBox)

    let size = pageRect.size

    pdfImagePageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    print("The size of the pdf is \(size)")

}
```

I then thought of just using the following but realised I cant because UIImage does not currently support pdf vector images

```
 let image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileName2)!

    image.drawInRect(pdfImagePageRect)
```

I just feel that there must be a way to insert a pdf vector image to a pdf document. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While UIImage doesn't support PDF files, Apple does provide a way to draw a PDF into a graphics context (whatever it is):

```
func CGContextDrawPDFPage(_ c: CGContext?, _ page: CGPDFPage?)
```

This would allow you to get your graphics context for the PDF you are writing, open your second PDF file, get a reference to the page and have the page rendered into your PDF context.

The only hard part is that you need to set the correct transformation matrix so that your PDF file that you are rendering is drawn in the correct location and with the scaling you want.

Also take a look at this page: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/ where it is shown how you can draw the correct part of the incoming PDF file. Essential code at that link is:

```
// url is a file URL
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);
CGPDFPageRef page1 = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);

// get the rectangle of the cropped inside
CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page1, kCGPDFCropBox);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, rect.size.width / mediaRect.size.width,
    rect.size.height / mediaRect.size.height);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -mediaRect.origin.x, -mediaRect.origin.y);

// draw it
CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page1);
```